# How do I get document field values for an item in Umbraco 7 backoffice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, umbraco7

I have created a custom Umbraco 7 dashboard. In it I want to get specific field details from instances of a known type of document type in my Umbraco CMS.

I have successfully obtained a list of all documents of a specific type by using `entityResource.getChildren(1386, "Document")`, and subsequently call `entityResource.getById(item.id, "Document")` on each such document. I can see many details for each document instance, but not the data the editor entered when creating it. How do I get this information using the Angular services/API of Umbraco?

Sample of dashboard code:

```
// get community alerts
entityResource.getChildren(1386, "Document")
    .then(function (ent)
    {
        angular.forEach(ent, function (item)
        {
            let communityalert = {
                umbracoItem: item,
                title: '',     // I want data from each document to put here
                topic: ''
            };
            entityResource
                .getById(item.id, "Document")
                .then(function (entity)
                {
                    console.log('entity', entity);
                    communityalert.title = entity.name;
                    communityalert.umbracoItem = entity;

                    entityResource
                        .getUrl(item.id, "Document")
                        .then(function (url)
                        {
                            communityalert.url = url;

                            // finally push collected data to VM.
                            vm.CommunityAlerts.push(communityalert);
                        });
                });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after much poking around I found the answer; **use the injectable contentResource's getById() method**. This gets **all** the details of a content item, in contrast the entityResource's getById() which just gets common details for a content tree, the latter resources methods gets you all a content items details; entered field data included.

```
contentResource.getById(item.id)
    .then((data) =>
    {
        //console.log('contentResource.getById data', data);
        angular.forEach(data.properties, (property) =>
        {
            //do something with the document's content...
        });
    });
```

So to summarise use methods in the injectable resource `entityResource` to get a sub set of details, but to get all details of a document use the injectable `contentResource` resource.

Simple when you read enough of the documentation!